# Combining 2 queries into 1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to optimize two queries into one, if possible.

My first query searches for all the authors of a lyrics... Then, for each author found, i want to find the total numbers of lyrics the author was involded in...

Right now, im executing the first query and for each row found, i'm launching another query to get the authors total lyrics he was involved... So, if there is 4  authors i will end up launching 4 more queries...
That is to many queries in my opinion. That is why i've decided to write here, so i can get help on how to optimize my query...

This is the query i'm executing to get the author(s) responsable for a lyrics:

```
$sql = "SELECT author.author_id, author.name
    FROM track INNER JOIN lyrics_author ON track.lyrics_id = lyrics_author.lyrics_id
    INNER JOIN author ON lyrics_author.author_id = author.author_id
    WHERE track.track_id = $trackid ";
```

This is the query to get the total number of lyrics the author as writing:

```
$total = "SELECT lyrics_author.author_id, count(*) as total
    FROM lyrics_author
    WHERE lyrics_author.author_id = $author_id
    GROUP BY lyrics_author.author_id";
```

This is a sample of the code:

```
<?php
$trackid = 5;

$sql = "SELECT author.author_id, author.name
    FROM track INNER JOIN lyrics_author ON track.lyrics_id = lyrics_author.lyrics_id
    INNER JOIN author ON lyrics_author.author_id = author.author_id
    WHERE track.track_id = $trackid ";

$result_author = @ $conn->query($sql);

while ($row_author = $result_author->fetch_assoc()) {
    $author_id = $row_author['author_id'];

    $total = "SELECT lyrics_author.author_id, count(*) as total
        FROM lyrics_author
        WHERE lyrics_author.author_id = $author_id
        GROUP BY lyrics_author.author_id";

    $result_total_lyrics = @ $conn->query($total);
    $t = $result_total_lyrics->fetch_assoc();

    echo $t['total'];

    $result_total_lyrics->free();
}

$result_author->free();
?>
```

Is it posible to optimize this query? If yes, how? Is there a link you could refer, so i can learn...

Thanks
Marco

Comment: You should remove the `@` from your query line. Hiding errors there means you won't be able to see any errors. This could lead to some hardship trying to figure out what's happening.

Comment: You're code is vulnerable to SQL injection. When employed, any script kiddie can hack into your database. I highly recommend reading up on some basic security before you start building serious web applications.

Comment: don't worry about security... as stated, this is a sample code, for readability purposes, not the real code... I've took care of sql injection in the real code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  author.author_id,
  author.name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT more_tracks.lyrics_id) AS total
FROM track
INNER JOIN lyrics_author USING (lyrics_id)
INNER JOIN author USING (author_id)
LEFT JOIN lyrics_author AS more_tracks USING (author_id)
WHERE track.track_id = $trackid
GROUP BY author.author_id
```

Answer (score 1):

That's confusing as heck. Why are you passing in a trackid as a lyricsid when you have a property called lyricsid??
Anyway

```
Select author.author_id, author.name, Count(*)
inner join
(SELECT lyrics_author.author_id 
FROM lyrics_author 
INNER JOIN tracks ON track.lyrics_id = lyrics_author.lyrics_id 
WHERE track.track_id = $lyricsid"; 
)  as lyricalauthors
inner join lyrics_author on lyrics_author.author_id = lyricalauthors.author_id
On author.author_id = lyricalauthors.author_id
Group By Author.author_id,author.name
```

I think ...

Comment: i've edited my sample code (sample, not real code) just when you wrote the answer... sorry for that